# A confusion about a question on photoelectric effect

Tags: homework-and-exercises, photoelectric-effect, discrete

Q. **Photoelectric effect supports quantum nature of light because**

1. There is minimum frequency of light below which no photoelectrons are emitted.
2. Electric charge of photoelectrons is quantized.
3. Maximum kinetic energy of photoelectrons depends only on the frequency of light and not on its intensity.
4. Even when metal surface is faintly illuminated the photoelectrons leave the surface immediately.

**Which of the following are correct?**

---

My take on this:

$$K\cdot E_{max}=h\nu-h\nu_{0}=h\nu-\phi_0$$ where:

$\nu$ - frequency of incident light,
$\nu_0$ - threshold frequency of metal

**Statement 1 is correct:** because threshold frequency exists. Below that threshold frequency no photoelectrons are emitted. There is no photoelectric current then.

**Statement 2 is correct:** Charge is always released in integral multiples of the basic charge $e=\mathrm{1.6\times 10^{-19} C}$.

**Statement 3 is correct:** It is an obvious fact. Max. K.E. of photoelectrons does not depend on intensity. Rather the photoelectric current alone changes.

**Statement 4 also is correct:** Again same reason as in statement 3.

But the options were these:

[image]

[image]

Now what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is a logic question. The quantisation of electric charges in electrons do not lend support to the quantisation of light in photons. Those two things are weakly linked, whereas all the other answers are much more directly tied together in a logical causal chain.

Comment: So this is the thing? Coz our NCERT (the Bible of India's physics) barely mentions about quantisation in it.

Comment: It is true that the electric charge is quantised, but this has nothing to do with the photoelectric effect.

Comment: Thanks for including the tag @JohnRennie, I myself forgot it. Anyways, a search on Google told me that wherever you see the charge is quantised. So IMO 2nd also should be correct. Or is it rather that they are asking specifically using the stem 'Photochemical effect supports quantum nature of light *because*...'?

Comment: They are specifically asking. Yes, that "because" is crucial.

Comment: > _Or is it rather that they are asking specifically using the stem 'Photochemical effect supports quantum nature of light because...'?_ - this.

Comment: Then I getcha...

Comment: Sorry if my question was too simple, but this was screwing me up like hell. I have an exam tomorrow and Modern physics is especially scoring.

Comment: 2-cond answer is omitted, because electric charge quantization and light quantization is only weakly linked through fine structure constant, namely $$\alpha ={\frac {e^{2}}{2\varepsilon _{0}hc}}$$. i.e. Planck constant $h$ used in $h\nu$ is what basically relates charge and light quantization. While other described photo-effect phenomena shows direct causal link of light quantization.